# How to update a nested entity in MongoDB using Java API

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I need to update the below Json like adding new entries inside the case1/case2 or updating the existing.How can I use the Update and set to perform this.And Also what if my Rest Service is a Patch.

```
 {
    "MyBson": [{
        "id": "someId",

        "name": "name123",

        "someEntity": [
            "A",
            "B"
        ],
        "someEntityParams": [{
                "case1": [{
                        "id": 133,
                        "name": "name"
                    },

                    {
                        "id": 124,
                        "name": "name1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "case2": [{
                        "id": 135,
                        "name": "name2",
                        "onemoreField": "field"
                    },

                    {
                        "id": 136,
                        "name": "name3",
                        "onemoreField": "field"
                    },

                    {
                        "id": 137,
                        "name": "name4",
                        "onemoreField": "field"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/16726186/4636715

Comment: I am mainly concerned of accessing and updating the someEntityParams .

Comment: Did you deserialize the JSON string to your POJOs? Or did you just want to manipulate the JSON string for update?

Comment: Just use the Request Json for Processing.I mean to update/patch

Comment: @LHCHIN  Sorry, I  receive the request as a POJO  and then do the processing of the pojo and then use MonDB API to update.

Comment: That why I asked you before! So I think you should edit your post to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet shows how to manipulate given JSON string with `Jackson` library to add new JSON node and update existing node with specific criteria.
You have to modify the logic to add/udpate nodes according to given request JSON string.

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonStr);

//create new node to be added
ObjectNode newNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
newNode.put("id", 125);
newNode.put("name", "name2");

ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) root.get("MyBson");
arrayNode.forEach(e -> {
    e.get("someEntityParams").forEach(e1 -> {
        //add new node of case1
        if (e1.has("case1")) {
            ((ArrayNode) e1.get("case1")).add(newNode);
        }

        //update existing node of case2 whose id is 136
        if (e1.has("case2")) {
            e1.get("case2").forEach(e2 -> {
                if (e2.get("id").asInt() == 136) {
                    ((ObjectNode) e2).put("onemoreField", "onemoreFieldNew");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
System.out.println(root.toString());
```

**Console output**

> {"MyBson":[{"id":"someId","name":"name123","someEntity":["A","B"],"someEntityParams":[{"case1":[{"id":133,"name":"name"},{"id":124,"name":"name1"},{"id":125,"name":"name2"}]},{"case2":[{"id":135,"name":"name2","onemoreField":"field"},{"id":136,"name":"name3","onemoreField":"onemoreFieldNew"},{"id":137,"name":"name4","onemoreField":"field"}]}]}]}